# Perform search in 3tier architecture

Tags: c#, winforms

i am all confused in 3 tier 
without using 3 tier this function worked

```
DataTable dt; 
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
            dv.RowFilter = string.Format("emp_f_name LIKE '%{0}%'",textBox1.Text);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;

        }
```

BUt in 3 tier 
i am all confused can u guys help me rewrite the code i am trying to search firstname in a textbox

in my bll class

```
public DataTable Display(string fname)
        {
            try
            {

                return obj.Display(fname);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

in my dal class

```
  public DataTable Display(string fname)
        {
            string query2;

            OpenCnn();
            query2 = "SELECT * FROM cntc_employee where fname='" +fname + "' ";
            sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query2, con);
            dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            CloseCnn();
            return dt;
        }
```

in ui class

```
 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string fname = txtfname.Text;
           DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
          dt = obj.Display(fname);
           dv.RowFilter = string.Format("emp_f_name LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox1.Text);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = obj.Display(this.txtfname.Text);
        }
```

Comment: **Do not concatenate SQL strings**, this is subject to SQL injection!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want? 
Your BLL class should be like this

```
public DataTable Display(string fname)
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable dt = obj.Display(fname);//call to DAL
                DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
                dv.RowFilter = string.Format("emp_f_name LIKE '%{0}%'",
                textBox1.Text);
                return dv.ToTable();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

In your UI

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string fname = txtfname.Text;
            dt = obj.Display(fname);// Call to BLL
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
```

in your DAL class

```
  public DataTable Display(string fname)
        {
            string query2;

            OpenCnn();
            query2 = "SELECT * FROM cntc_employee where fname='" +fname + "' ";
            sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query2, con);
            dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            CloseCnn();
            return dt;
        }
```

Comment: @skates008 great. if this answer suits means mark it as ans.

Comment: can u help me little i have written query like this
 query = "SELECT * FROM cntc_employee where emp_f_name='" +fname + "' ";
how do u use LIKE '%{0}%'" in above query

Comment: @skates008 string.Format("SELECT * FROM cntc_employee where fname='" +fname + ' AND fname LIKE %{0}%",fname);

Comment: sry not working m not using string.format
query = "SELECT * FROM cntc_employee where emp_f_name='" +fname + "' ";// this query matches whole input